# MYSQL Query to retrieve current month data as well as check for last month

Tags: mysql

I have a table work_history('id','name','work','work_month','work_year').

I need a query to current current month data, but if data is not exist for current month, in this case retrieve last month data so on.....till then data not found.
nly 
For Ex- If data found for 11-2012 so retrieve only this data, no need to check for previous month, but if not found so check for last month 10-2012. If again not found check 09-2012.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what did you try, please post some code

Answer (score 0):

The month that you want is the maximum month that is available in the data. it must be either the current month or the closest to it. so such query should look like:

```
select ......
from work_history
where work_month = (select max(work_month) from work_history)
```

note that if the column work_month is a char column, you might need to convert the data to date type in order to allow correct comparison. based on the format seen in the example above:

```
select ......
from work_history
where str_to_date(work_month,'%m-%Y') = (select max(str_to_date(work_month,'%m-%Y')) from work_history)
```

**EDIT**

following all comments, the following query should fix the mistake I had and also give data based on ID of the user:

```
select wh.*
from work_history wh, 
  (select id, max(str_to_date(work_month,'%m-%Y')) as mx_month 
   from work_history 
   where str_to_date(work_month,'%m-%Y') <= curdate()  
   group by id             
  ) wh2
where wh.id=wh2.id
and str_to_date(wh.work_month,'%m-%Y') = wh2.mx_month
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this would be helpful for me.

But in my case in this table work_history('id', user_id,'name','work','work_month','work_year').

Comment: actually i have a mistake, i will edit my post. I assumed the data does not contain months that are higher than the current month, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this would be helpful for me.

But in my case in this table work_history('id', user_id,'name','work','work_month','work_year').

If user_id = 1 has records in month 10-2012 but user_is = 2 has records in 09-2012, so this query retrieve data only for user_id = 1.

Comment: you did not specify anything regarding that in your question. you should make it clear you need that per user in the question itself. anyway, I ask again, what is the type of your work_month column?